# How to batch copy files based on a list (txt) in to another folder with same directory structure?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a root directory with over 25,000 files in it. These files are in loads of different subdirectories.

I also have a text file with 4300 lines in it, each line is an absolute path to one of the files in the directory. Like below,

```
c:\dir1\hat1.gif
c:\dir1\hat2.gif
c:\dir1\dir2\hat1.gif
c:\dir1\dir2\hat2.gif
c:\dir1\dir3\cat.zip
c:\dir1\dir3\banana.exe
```

I also have another root directory witch is a copy of the original root directory structure but all the directories are empty.

I would like to copy all the files listed in the text file to the directory which is empty and place all the copied files inn the respected subdirectories.

if I use the following batchfile I keep getting file overwrite prompts because it is not copying the files to the correct directories.

```
@echo off
set dst_folder=c:\DSTN2
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (USEDFILES.txt) DO (
    xcopy /S/E "%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

How do I modify this so the files are copied to the correct directory?

Comment: What is the difference between this question, and [the one you asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68863249) and have now deleted. What happened when you tried to implement the advice provided to you in those comments? If you show a pattern of behavior which ignores the advice of commentors, they'll be less likely to assist you in future. Change `"%dst_folder%"` to `"%dst_folder%%%~pi"`

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it worked. The difference it that I managed to create the duplicate folder structure, editing the existing question would have just lead to confusion because the initial replies would have not tallied up to the question.

Comment: @dij, we really prefer you keep it all in one question instead of deleting it.  When you edit a question everyone can see the edits you made.  Comments below questions can be deleted as well.  Before you ask any further questions, please take the [tour] like you were asked to when you joined StackOverFlow.  Also read [ask] a good question and always provide a [mcve] of the code and input examples you are using

Answer (score 2):

Since you are copying specific files from a list, you need to make sure the directory structure exists in the destination if you want it in a similar folder structure. So using the power of the `FOR` command modifiers you can get the file path only from the file name in the file list.  You will use that modifier to create the destination directory and also use it as the destination for the `XCOPY` command.

I have taken the liberty of providing best practices for all the code you are using.

```
@echo off

set "dst_folder=c:\DSTN2"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("USEDFILES.txt") DO (
    mkdir "%dst_folder%%%~pG" 2>NUL
    xcopy "%%~G" "%dst_folder%%%~pG"
)
```

Comment: Just be aware that there is no need to use `MkDir`/`MD` for this task, because `xcopy.exe` will create the tree if it does not already exist, (subject to permissions), as long as the destination directory has a trailing backward slash. Luckily the `%~p` expansion carries a leading and trailing backward slash already, so just using `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe`, _(for best practice)_, with source `"%%G"` and destination `"%dst_folder%%%~pG"` is sufficient for this particular task, assuming that the drive specification in the value of `%dst_folder%` does exist, _(it doesn't create drives)_.